# Dynamically added Angular2 component doesn't get rendered but the statically added does

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I'm executing the following method when the user clicks a button.

```
@ViewChild("privs") privs: ElementRef;
addPrivs() {
  this.privs.nativeElement
    .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<generic1>yey!</generic1>');
}
```

My markup looks like this.

```
<generic1>woosh</generic1>
<div #privs></div>
```

The subcomponent named *generic1* is declared like this and, of course, present in *imports* of the module.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "generic1",
  template: "<div>mamba...</div>"
})
export class Generic1 { }
```

The behavior I'm getting is that the statistically created one in the markup shows as supposed to. The dynamically appended don't. According to the DOM as I investigate, a tag *generic1* is added but it's not rendered by Angular (I see the text *yey!* and the tag but not the rendition of the component).

What am I missing?

I've googled for examples but didn't see anything specifically wrong with my set up. Must be something outside of my scope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually creating a dynamic component.  You are inserting additional HTML that is not rendered by Angular.  Html and text are sanitized when inserting them into a template like that and thus you won't get a rendered component.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38888009/3197720) has a very detailed explanation of setting up dynamic components.  However, it is not a copy and paste solution for what you need.  The [documentation on Angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) has a good example of a dynamic component loader.  Essentially, you will need a `ComponentFactoryResolver` to resolve and build an Angular component.  In the example from the Angular.io docs, the real magic happens in this function:

```
loadComponent() {
    this.currentAddIndex = (this.currentAddIndex + 1) % this.ads.length;
    let adItem = this.ads[this.currentAddIndex];
    let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);
    let viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
  }
```

It retrieves a component from a list of stored components in `this.ads`, uses a `componentFactoryResolver` to resolve and build the component.  It retrieves the `viewContainerRef` and creates the component on it.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.